# Eclipse content assist auto-activation for CSS?

Tags: css, eclipse, ide

I found there is content assist auto-activation option for Java, JavaScript and XML. But not for CSS. So I have to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> like crazy. Any way to make the auto-completion box show up automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to open a feature request in Bugzilla for this.

http://bugs.eclipse.org/